# How to monitor an actuator's feedback line from a microcontroller?

Tags: actuator

[image: AG-020-B Electric actuator wiring diagram]

the AG-020-B electric actuator is controlled from a microcontroller. Terminal 1 is connected to the DC PSU GND, Terminal 2 is connected to the +24VDC via a high side Power MOSFET(TPS22810) as shown below. This is for power saving.

[image: Power to actuator on/off]

Low side MOSFET (AUIPS1021) Q5A and Q5B are used to control the opening/closing of the valve via terminal 3 and 4. The microcontroller I/O lines Valve_Ctrl_1a and Valve_Ctrl_1b provide a 3.3V signal.

[image: control of valves]

- Comments are welcome regarding the power and switching circuitry.
- Any suggestion on how to monitor the feedback lines on terminal 8 and 10 from a microcontroller. A lamp is not suitable as the system will be enclosed in a box.

Comment: The limit switches produce contact closure between 7 and 8 when the actuator is closed, and between 9 and 10 when it is open.  You may wire these terminals to whatever sort of indicator you like.

Answer (score 1):

It should be: terminal 1 & 2 connected to PSU , no need to be controlled by MCU.
The terminals 3 & 4 are switshed to terminal 1 as depicted using your low side switch (of course the device is connected to DC PSU). Once the valve opens/closes you can turn off the signal. The voltage IMO is the same as supply voltage.

Comment: Terminal 2 is controlled by MCU to cut off the power completely to the valve once switched.

Comment: @user49395 I guess it already switched off using terminals 1,2. No need to complicate things

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, If terminal 2 is always connected to the battery then there is a continuous nominal current draw of 0.2A

Comment: Any suggestion on how to monitor the feedback lines on terminal 8 and 10 from a microcontroller. a Lamp is not suitable as the system will be enclosed in a box?